# How do I subscribe to an SQL InfoMessage from a different class?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two classes:

`Class Home` which is my form and has a list box waiting for all the InfoMessage's sent from  `Class SQL`.

I want to know how I can pass `Class SQL` `InfoMessages` to `Class Home`.

In `Class SQL` my code is as follows:

```
public void runSqlCmd(string sqlCmd, Boolean dsRequired)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                con.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
                {
                     sqlMsg += "\n" + e.Message;
                };

                if (dsRequired)
                {
                    ds.Clear();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, con);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
                else if (!dsRequired)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                throw sqlEx;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Where the code has:

```
con.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
                        {
                             sqlMsg += "\n" + e.Message;
                        };
```

is how I want to

My `ClassHome` code is:

```
private void btn_getLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        tb_location.Clear();
        if (cb_database.Text != null)
        {
            updateConString();
            _sql.runSqlCmd(_sqlScripts.getLocation, _sqlScripts.dsRequired);
            foreach (DataTable table in _sql.ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    tb_location.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not catch and immediately rethrow. The point of catching is to handle the error - if you're not actually handling it, then don't catch in the first place! And don't do `throw sqlEx;`. You lose your stack trace and it's more confusing to debug. Just put `throw;` if you're going to rethrow the same exception, or create a new exception with the original one as the inner exception and throw the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find example in this article [ADO-NET-Asynchronous-SQL-Calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42266/ADO-NET-Asynchronous-SQL-Calls)

You need to write someting like this

```
public class ClassHome
{
    public static void ConnectionInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            // Check to make sure we are information only messages
            Console.WriteLine("Received {0} messages", e.Errors.Count);
            foreach (SqlError info in e.Errors)
            {
                if (info.Class > 9) // Severity
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Message : {0} :   State : {1}", info.Message, info.State);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Info Message : {0} :   State : {1}", info.Message, info.State);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received Connection Info Message : {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Then subscribe from SQL Class

```
command.Connection.InfoMessage += ClassHome.ConnectionInfoMessage;
```

Comment: Can I replace `Console.WriteLine` with `lb.Items.Add` (where lb = listbox).

My `ClassHome` has a function which submits the SQL statement. Does the `ConnectionInfoMessage` just work on it's own or how do I merge them together.

Comment: Yes, you can replace. For second question - ConnectionInfoMessage just work on it's own